# ACS71020 EEPROM factory settings

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement

I've recently taken over a project that has issues with the ACS71020. The values that we get are off, and the software has written to both the EEPROM and the shadow registers with custom values. My understanding is that the default values in register B is factory calibrated, and once overwritten there is no way to restore. The datasheet do not mention any default values for this register.

Is this correct, or have I misunderstood something?

Link to datasheet: https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs71020-datasheet.ashx

Comment: First place an order for a few new chips and a basic hot air rework tool so that you aren't stuck wasting even more time.  In the future, consider having your MCU load custom values into the shadow registers for a session only, without touching the factory settings in EPROM, or if you decide to use the EPROM first back up the factory values in your prototypes against board serial numbers.  In the meantime you might take some data at a variety of currents against a trusted meter.

Comment: There will very likely not be *default values* for these registers; this is not an uncommon approach in many measurement devices to provide correction values that compensate for manufacturing variation. The values would have been determined at factory test and burned to EEPROM at that time.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. :) 
New parts have been ordered, and I've already removed the part of the software that wrote to the eeprom, and no it was not my code.